# Which is fast way to compile Ginger Bread source code?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-ndk

I am working on Ginger Bread source code. First time compilation require 3 to 4 hours. After first compilation, when I execute make command, it takes only 10 to 15 minutes to compile. What can I do to reduce the time of the first compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using ccache to increase overall performance
2. Using ramdisk

Also reference [this article](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Howto%3a_Speed_up_building#Decrease_compile_time).

Comment: `ccache` may help if you change c code, it won't if you touch .java files. Besides getting a faster PC (many cores + a ssd) you could try to play with the amount of parallel make jobs (`make -j6`) for 6 (you should have at least 4 cores then).